# Python how to open any file without explicit application call

Tags: python

I was wondering if there was a way to open a file and have the OS/Python handle what applications to use to open it like how the OS typically does.

For example if I have the path of a pdf file, it would automatically open the pdf file with the default pdf reader like adobe. If it is a mp4 file, it would use default video player like VLC. Or if it is a text file it would use notepad.

Do I have to explicitly handle each file extension or is there an easier way?